# apache - pipe logs to a script - while not spawning script multiple times

Tags: apache-2.4

I want to pipe apache logs (with my custom format) to my script. I at the same time want to keep loging standard format for every vhost to separate file.

When I put 
CustomLog "|/path/to/my/script" myformat
in httpd.conf it works perfect but only for vhosts that has no 
CustomLog /path/to/logs/vhostXX-logfile otherformat
inside

For vhosts that has already logging in it it does not log anything to |/path/to/my/script

I could put 
CustomLog "|/path/to/my/script" myformat
in every vhost but then script gets spawned in paralel for every single vhost and that is not acceptable.

What can I do?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can do what you want in the way you are trying because of your restriction to not have multiple instances of your script.

You may get some mileage out of having the vhosts log to a named pipe and having your script read from that.

Answer (score 0):

It's not currently possible in 2.4. GlobalLog directive was added to trunk for basically this purpose but was not backported.